# Axis Label Truncated in highcharter Barplot

Tags: r, r-highcharter

This looks as expected:

```r
df <- structure(list(surveillance_diag = c("Meningitis", "Sepsis"), 
                     y = c(1239L, 7850L), color = c("#1f78b4", "#e31a1c"), 
                     freq = c(14, 86)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


library(highcharter)
library(magrittr)

highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = "") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$surveillance_diag) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = df, type = "bar", hcaes(x = surveillance_diag, y = y, color = color))
```

[image]

But the same code with a data frame of only one row/category will cut the category label.

```r
df <- df[1, ]

highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = "") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$surveillance_diag) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = df, type = "bar", hcaes(x = surveillance_diag, y = y, color = color))
```

[image]

How can I ensure that the label is properly displayed regardless of the number of categories?

Comment: I get the error "The quosure environment should be explicitly supplied as `env`"

Comment: Can't reproduce this error. Could be worth making sure that you use recent versions of those packages.

Comment: You are right, had installed a dev version. My bad

Comment: @mnist could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431981/how-to-create-two-independent-drill-down-plot-using-highcharter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `categories` as a list helps here.

```r
highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = "") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = as.list(df$surveillance_diag)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = df, type = "bar", hcaes(x = surveillance_diag, y = y, color = color))
```

[image]